# Catch a exception in request, without specify one by one

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller

Application Architecture:

- MVC .NET C# application
- Have two Layers: A DB Layer communication (that catch and treats errors) and application Layer that treats the web requests/responses.
- DB Layer doesn't tell to application layer some important errors that occurs (example: timeout request data base, database is not found/down ... );

What I want it is in application Layer, catch that like timeout request data base and treat them one by one, instead of treat them (like is happening right now) the all the same way.

*I do not have access to DB Layer code*

Questions:

- It is possible?
- If it is possible, it is *correct* program like I want?

Thank you.

Comment: It is not clear (at least to me) if you are talking about catching specific first-chance exceptions, or unhandled app domain exceptions? Anyway, it's certainly not standard programming practice to catch first-chance exceptions, except for extraordinary (debugging/troubleshooting) purposes. Also, does you DB layer perhaps throw aggregate exceptions? I.e. perhaps you just need to check the `InnerException` in that case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add to @Matías' answer, it's also possible to get [notified about first chance exceptions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997368(v=vs.110).aspx) from an app domain. This means you can have a handler which will process all exceptions thrown in your code, even if they are caught:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += UnhandledExceptionHandler;
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FirstChanceException += FirstChanceExceptionHandler;
```

For example, if you write something like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // attach mentioned handlers
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += 
        (sender, e) => Dump("Unhandled exception", e.ExceptionObject);
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FirstChanceException += 
        (sender, e) => Dump("First chance exception intercepted", e.Exception);

    // this will get intercepted by the FirstChanceException handler
    try
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Thrown inside try/catch");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("This was caught: " + ex.Message);
    }

    // this will get intercepted by the FirstChanceException handler
    // and then caught by UnhandledException handler
    throw new InvalidOperationException("Thrown OUTSIDE try/catch");
}

private static void Dump(string info, object exception)
{
    var ex = (Exception)exception;
    Console.WriteLine(info + ": " + ex.Message);
}
```

You will get the following output:

```
First chance exception intercepted: Thrown inside try/catch
This was caught by the catch clause: : Thrown inside try/catch

First chance exception intercepted: Thrown OUTSIDE try/catch
Unhandled exception: Thrown OUTSIDE try/catch
```

Obviously, you can expect a whole bunch of first chance exceptions, so be prepared for some filtering logic inside that handler method.

Comment: Yeah (about your valuable addition). BTW I still think that using these events couldn't be the best idea if the underlying framework provides a way to handle this scenarios. That's why I gave the example of ASP.NET Web API and others

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer: sure, I wouldn't personally use this approach for anything other that troubleshooting.

Answer (score 1):

If both *layers* are in the same physical *tier*, you can use [`AppDomain.UnhandledException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception(v=vs.110).aspx) event in your application layer.

> If it is possible, it is correct program like I want?

While this question is very subjective, it's not uncommon to have a *catch all* code to handle unhandled exceptions and perform actions like logging messages or showing errors to the UI to notify the user that something went wrong.

For example, ASP.NET WebAPI has both the *exception filters* and *exception handlers*. Old ASP.NET apps had the `Global.asax` *Application_Error* event, and many other frameworks have their global exception handling points.